# How to account for overlap in individual studies in meta-analysis of meta-analyses (umbrella analysis)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, meta-analysis, precision, metafor

I want to conduct a meta-analysis of meta-analyses (aka umbrella analysis). A potential issue is that within each individual meta-analysis I want to include there is some overlap between the studies. Is this likely to create a problem of dependence and artificially inflate the precision of the estimates?

Is there anything that could be done to overcome this?

Comment: Yes, you can't double count the primary studies. So either you extract the studies and include studies only once, or you don't do a meta-analysis. That's one of the limitations of overviews of reviews/ umbrella reviews.

Comment: The first question is what you are trying to do with the various meta-analyses. If you are planning to synthesize the findings from the various meta-analyses using statistical methods, then indeed you need to account for study overlap. However, one could also just put the various meta-analyses side by side, discuss differences in inclusion criteria, studies, outcomes, findings, and so on without trying to synthesize the pooled estimates from the various MAs.

Comment: Thanks both, very useful. Ideally we would like to synethise the findings statistically. I also came across this paper (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0272735813000275) which attempts to weight the individual meta-analysis by their uniqueness.